# Using VisualSVN: I want to configure the post-commit.cmd hook to send email to myself

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

Here is my post-commit.cmd hook:

```
"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^
    commit-notification "%1" -r %2 ^
    --from $(author)@example.com --to myname@example.com ^
    --smtp-server smtp.example.com
```

In the script `$(author)` converts to myname and myname is what I use to authenticate. No problems here. I receive the email to `myname@example.com`.

I tried to use `$(author)` as the `--to` value and the hook fails. How can I configure the hook to use myname as the `--to` value without using `myname@example.com`. Is there another way to use the `$(author)` variable?

--

I found my solution using svnlook.exe with a temp file.
Messy but it works. Lucky for me this is a small team of developers.

`"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\svnlook.exe" author c:\Repositories\software > 
C:\Repositories\software\hooks\SET_TO_USER.tmp`

`set /p DEF_TO_USER=<C:\Repositories\software\hooks\SET_TO_USER.tmp`

`if %DEF_TO_USER%==mike (set SEND_TO_USER=mike.doe)`

`"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^`

`commit-notification "%1" -r %2 ^`

`--from $(author)noreply.com ^`

`--to %SEND_TO_USER%@example.com ^`

`--smtp-server smtp.example.com`